# Query after mutation in graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

there's something I suppose it should be easy but I can not find out the answer after searching the web for a long time:

I was just trying to make a mutation using graphql then refresh data using another graphql query *afterwards*, how can I make this happen inside only one HTTP(graphql) request?

Failed trys:

1. I tried sending two graphql schemas wrapped inside one array use [batching](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#batching), but it's async and the query gets back before the mutation which is not desired.
2. I tried to write the same query using mutation which actually mutates nothing and put that after the real mutation, this works but I don't believe this is the optimized solution for this.
3. Also, I know there's something like `update`(refetchQuery) etc by apollo-client(react), but how can I do this without any client framework?

Thanks:)

related links:

- [Mutation and a query in the same time](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql/issues/180)
- [Can I avoid using refetchQueries with Apollo GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772662/can-i-avoid-using-refetchqueries-with-apollo-graphql)

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the mutation result so that you get the query data directly without an additional query?

Comment: Thanks, this is surely a good solution. But the problem is when I can not decide what the response should look like or there's more complicated data I need. I think these cases do exist, but your answer do works in your case.

Comment: In that case, maybe Interfaces and Union Types will help. You can read about them here: http://graphql.org/learn/schema/ I don't have experience using them, but maybe they could be part of the solution for your case.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to send a mutation and in the same request/query send a query that waits for the mutation to finish before being resolved. From the specifications perspective this is simply not possible (yet). You can read the specification [here](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/October2016/) (I know technical specification sounds scary but if you are already a bit familiar with GraphQL it is easy to read :-) ).

The idea is that a mutation result is designed to potentially return the data that has been updated. I read in an article a while ago about the query object type. The article highlights how the type is just a normal object type and can be simply returned in a mutation result. While **I would not recommend this pattern** since I think the mutation result should explicitly list all updated objects it is certainly possible and can be a solution for very complicated cases (like the one you describe). To make this a bit more visual here is an example schema:

```
type ExampleMutationResult {
  success: Boolean!
  query: Query!
}

type Query {
  queryField: String!
}

type Mutation {
  exampleMutation: ExampleMutationResult!
}

# Query would look like this
mutation example {
  exampleMutation {
    success
    query {
      queryField
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the tradeoff is relatively high and can only be enabled when you can change the schema. I would check first if the overhead of the second HTTP request really needs optimisation.

Comment: Wow, nested resolver right? That should be a clever workable solution as well. But as you pointed out, this is not a recommended solution either, thanks very much tho. Maybe I should wait for something like request control flow or some new feature in specs.